# Ruby on Rails: How to create a class schedule calendar with hour by hour breakdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table, schedule

I'm a new ruby on rails coder who is trying to create a neatly displayed calendar of the week for students to check their timetables.

I have stored the lessons in a table with the following data:

> :course_id, :state_unit_code, :day_of_week, :start_date, :end_date, :start_time, :end_time, :classroom_id, :campus_id, :lecturer_id

I wish to take the data from that table and transform it into an html table similar to that shown:

[image]

I've mocked it up using table, tr td rowspan colspan and so on.

If you can point me in the right direction I'd be most appreciable.

Follows on from a post by another user ([allesklar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19893/allesklar)): [How would you build this daily class schedule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427689/how-would-you-build-this-daily-class-schedule)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a gem for this unless you are a strong confident rails programmer with some decent experience.  It's a good project if you're just doing it to learn but not so much if you actually want it to be used as a 'production app. in the real world.

I think that https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar might meet your needs.  Take a look and see.

You may also need to use a separate gui date picker at some point and their are many solutions for that such as http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/ though this is just about picking dates, not the full calendar display of event also.  But it could be handy.  You'll also see 30 (!) different date pickers here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-calendar-plugins/ that also include ones that let you span dates.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will have a look at the gem. I also do not mind going into the code to learn how it being done.

Comment: Hi Michael. Well the event_calendar is a little raw in what it can handle, and being new to the ruby/rails scene I'm finding it a little difficult to manipulate. I will have to delve into the code to see what I can work out. I've asked a question in its google group to see what I get in the way of assistance. Cheers.